# How do I evenly space radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

My radio button won't space out evenly. I've tried adding, "margin-right: 250px;" along with another method but they will not give me the result that I'm looking for. I want the buttons to be evenly spaced out on the page and stay center aligned. Also I've tried adding style the the text next to the radio buttons but I don't know how to incorporate it in the CSS of my code. The code does work in the body though.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DJsP/embedded/result/

Here's the CSS:

```
#navlist li {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
style="color:#fa7f28; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you control the markup, an easy way would be to wrap the radio buttons and associated text in `span` elements, set the `display` of the `span` to `inline-block`, and set a common width.

```
<span><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="AT&T" />ATT</span>
<span><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Other" />Other</span>
<span><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Unlocked" />Unlocked</span>
```

CSS:

```
#navlist li span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2DJsP/3/

Comment: I've tried this. The 6em can't be increased. I want more space between the radio buttons.

Comment: What do you mean? Increase the space to `10em` or some other arbitrary value in the fiddle and the radio buttons move farther apart.

Comment: Yeah but I want the spacing to be greater than just 10em but when I increase the "em" it just distorts the form.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "it just distorts the form." Can you be more descriptive? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: The radio buttons just move out of place. I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome also.

Comment: Do you mean up, down, left, or right? Adding more space in between the radio buttons pushes them further apart, but they're still centered in the window. Did you want the buttons to be vertical?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37388/discussion-between-pete-and-user2680614)

Answer (score 3):

Given the HTML markup you currently have, the following CSS is the approach that uses the least amount of CSS:

```
#navlist li > input { display:inline-block; margin:0 5px 0 50px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DJsP/4/

Note, `margin` and `padding` don't apply to *inline* elements. Using a display of `inline-block` enables the usage of `margin`s and `padding`, while keeping the elements, along with their associated text, in the current flow.

Comment: I increased the 50 to 200 and it seem that the code moves towards the left of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/2DJsP/5/embedded/result/

Comment: @user2680614 what were you expecting?

Comment: I want it to be evenly spaced on the page and centered.

Comment: then you'll need to tinker with the margins i've set, along with centering the radio buttons containers ...

Comment: In fact, horizontal margin and padding *do* apply to inline elements, but only between the element and its previous/next inline siblings, not between parts of the element itself when it's wrapped into several lines. If there is only one line, horizontal margins and paddings of inline and inline-block elements behave very similarly.

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers, you can evenly distribute elements using Flexbox with `justify-content: space-between;`:

```
#navlist li {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

For other browsers, you can emulate this (kind of) using `text-align: justify` and pseudo-element trick to force line wrapping. See both examples [in this **edited fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DJsP/6/).

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but how do you change the amount of space between the radio buttons?

Comment: @user2680614, it's changing automatically. Browser just distributes the extra horizontal space between the flex items (in Flexbox version) or between words (in text-align version), this is how these CSS properties work.